# Lock keyword and application resets

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a web service that freezes deadlocks on the lock command.

```
lock(typeof(MyServiceType))
```

I feel that this is caused by application pool resets.

Is there any way that app pool resets could cause the lock to become a forever lock?

Comment: Don't lock on instances of `Type`! In general, you should never `lock` on something that someone else could `lock` on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't exactly comment on what is happening with regards to application pool resets, but perhaps you should try locking on a new object, instead?

```
  private readonly object myLock = new object();

  void DoSomething()
  {
    lock(myLock)
    {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not normally.

App pools are process isolated. The only way you can get a problem is when the app pool can't shutdown due to that deadlock. (This would be a DOS and therefore likely a bug in IIS.)

Thinking of it now, really, this could be your problem. You are locking on a Type (*typeof* MyServiceType). Could you try locking on something else (that perhaps wouldn't prevent unloading the containing assembly from the AppDomain in IIS?). Something like the following is idiomatic:

```
 public class MyServiceType : //....
 {
      private static readonly Object _lockObject = new Object();

      // ....

      lock(_lockObject)
      {
           ....
      }
```